# Delete from file block of lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file in which the info id organized in block of lines.
I need to delete the blocks that contain some information.

For example I have the following

```
dn: CN=Publishers,OU=ABC - Groups 
changetype: add 
cn: Cert 
description:   Members of this group are permitted to ... 
groupType: -2 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: group

dn: CN=Domain Guests,OU=ABC - Groups, 
changetype: add 
cn: Domain Guests 
description: All domain guests 
groupType: -21 
objectClass: top
objectClass: group

dn: CN=Domain Computers,OU=ABC- Groups 
changetype: add 
cn: Domain Computers 
description: All workstations  
groupType: -2 
objectClass:top 
objectClass: group

dn: CN=AS Servers,OU=ABC- Groups 
changetype: add 
cn: AS   Servers
description: Servers in this group... 
groupType: -214
objectClass: top 
objectClass: group

dn: CN=Domain Controllers,OU=ABC - Groups 
changetype: add 
cn: Domain Controllers 
description: All domain controllers in the domain
groupType: -21 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: group

dn: CN=Domain Users,OU=ABC - Groups 
changetype: add 
cn: Domain Users
description: All domain users 
groupType: -21 
objectClass: top
objectClass: group
```

And I need to remove for example the blocks which have the name contained in another file for example the first line for some blocks are in othe file (e.g. `CN=Domain Computers,OU=ABC- Groups and CN=AS Users,OU=ABC- Groups (those bellow)`

My code :

```
$listsharedCN=Get-content "shared.txt
$exported_groups= Get-Content "groups.txt
$listsharedCN | % {
$var=($_ -split '`n')[0]

if(($exported_groups | % { ($_ -split '`n')[0] }) -match[regex]::Escape($var)) 
 {
    #I found the first line of the block but need to delete this block  "
 }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A simpler observation is that those entries your looking to remove dont have a whitespace inbetween the previous word and the hyphen. Is that a typo or does it not matter? The string MeetingRoom does not appear in your sample data either

Comment: I edited the text again. It was a mistake because I used the string to test and I do not know why the text was saved without the white spaces between(in fact it is new line between the rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure what exactly you are doing with this data it would be tonnes easier to manipulate it if it was an Object....... LETS DO THAT! *From comments:* I feel like I over complicated the issue after I found out what you were doing with the data after the fact. While this should work I would suggest that if you ever have a question to put some code with input data ( if required ) and desired out.

```
$rawFile = Get-Content -Raw -Path E:\temp\data.txt
$excludesFile = Get-Content -Path E:\temp\shared.txt

$ldifdes = $rawFile -split '\s+(?=dn:)' | ForEach-Object{
    # Empty hashtable that we will use to build a single custom object
    $props = @{}

    $entityObject = $_ -split "`r`n" 

    # Parse out the object class. Custom object cannot have more than one key
    # so we convert to Array instead.
    $entityObject | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch 'objectclass'} | ForEach-Object{
        # Populate the object that are not objectclass into $props
        $parameter = $_ -split ":"
        $props.($parameter[0]) = ($parameter[1]).Trim()
    }

    # Address the objectclass now.
    $props.ObjectClass = @()
    $entityObject | Where-Object{$_ -match 'objectclass'} | ForEach-Object{
        $props.ObjectClass += (($_ -split ":")[1]).Trim()
    } 

    New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property $props
}

# Filter out the entries we do not need.
$regex = "($($excludesFile -join "|"))"
$ldifdes | Where-Object{$_.DN -notmatch $regex} | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Output "dn: $($_.DN)"
    Write-Output "changetype: $($_.changetype)"
    Write-Output "cn: $($_.cn)"
    Write-Output "description: $($_.description)"
    Write-Output "groupType: $($_.groupType)"
    $_.ObjectClass | ForEach-Object{
        Write-Output "ObjectClass: $_"
    }
    # Add a blank
    Write-Output ""
} | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath "E:\temp\output.txt"
```

If you have at least powershell 3.0 this code will work. Not a big deal to downgrade if need be. Without going into to much detail:

1. Read the files raw contents
2. Split those contents into there variable groups
3. For each one of those group split again into a string array
4. For each string in the string array split by colon to get the key and value
5. Exception being ObjectClass which we convert into an array since a hashtable need to have unique keys
6. Build a regex of items we want to exclude and parse them out with a `Where-Object`
7. For simplicity sake ( since i feel i made this worse ) use a series of `Write-Ouput`'s to display the data for ldifde
8. Pipe into `Out-File`

**Less Complicated**

```
$rawFile = Get-Content -Raw -Path E:\temp\data.txt
$excludesFile = Get-Content -Path E:\temp\shared.txt
$regex = "($($excludesFile -join "|"))"

$results = $rawFile | select-string -pattern '(?smi)(dn:).*?(?=dn:|\Z)' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {$_.Value.Trim()}

$results | Where-Object{ $_ -notmatch $regex } | ForEach-Object{$_ + [Environment]::NewLine} | 
        Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath "E:\temp\output.txt"
```

Parse the strings into block groups. Build `$regex` string just like before and use that as an exclusion in `Where-Object`. Then just output to file using `Out-File`

Answer (score 0):

```
dn:\s+CN=(?:Domain\s+Computers|AS\s+Users),OU=ABC\s*-\s+Groups.*?\n
```

You can try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/10

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you are trying to do, so I will give you some general guideline. You could turn this file into a CSV formatted file and then read it in with ConvertFrom-Csv. You then have an array of proper objects to work with.

Example (you can put all of this on one line):

```
Get-Content .\ExportGroups.ldf | % { $_ -replace ' (\w+:)', ';' -replace 'dn: ', ''} | 
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header DN, ChangeType, CN, Description, GroupType, ObjectClass, ObjectClass2
```

I'll explain it, because it's a bit cryptic.

- Get all the lines of the file with Get-Content
- Use -replace with regex to create valid CSV formatted lines
- Create PowerShell objects from the CSV with ConvertFrom-CSV